# Which processing method to use

Tags: sql-server, ssas, partition

I need to apply a Processing method for the Cube, Containing Transactions measure (weekly partitioned). When the last week's data is available, Which kind of processing method should I choose so that it does not impact other customer reports while processing?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In short: MOLAP. However, you'd have to provide additional information to get a more accurate answer. Take a look at the following link: [StorageTypes](http://bageshkumarbagi-msbi.blogspot.com/2014/12/storage-mode-in-cube-ssas-2008_36.html) (there's a summary table at the bottom of the post) and try to figure out the best MOLAP storage type for your particular business case.